# how to handle scope from setInterval javascript?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, closures

```
define(['services/tempService'], function (TempService) {

"use strict";

window.TempClass = {
setIntervalConst : 0,
startTimer: function(){
    var that = this;
    this.setIntervalConst = setInterval(function () {
        that.checkTime();
    }, 1000);
},

checkTime: function() {
    new TempService().getData();
}
};
  return window.TempClass;
});
```

tempService.js

```
define([], function() {

"use strict";

var TempService = function(){

 return{
   getData: function(){
     Service.getData(URL);
  }
};       
};
 return TempService;
});
```

i am trying to access the checkTime function from startTimer function, but it is throwing "TempService is not a function." error
how to handle scope in this case ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with scope. You need to fix `services/tempService` so it returns a function.

Comment: @Quentin updated question with tempService.js

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to call
    `new TempService().getData()`
just call
    `TempService.getData()`
because you are passing an object in as a parameter so you should already have an instance.